# Is there a way to update host_vars file in Ansible from a task?

Tags: ansible

I have a host_vars file with a variable `mgmt_ip: "192.168.1.10"`

In the playbook, I get an IP from an output and I would like to update this `mgmt_ip` for the next tasks within the playbook.

Comment: No you can't update host_vars but you can use facts you set in your playbooks (set_fact) and pass that information along to a role or play

Answer (score 3):

You can simply run a local task to update the variable value directly in the file.

```
- local_action:
    module: lineinfile
    dest: ./host_vars/file
    regexp: 'mgmt_ip:'
    line: 'mgmt_ip: xx.xx.xx.xx'
```

The change won't however be reflected immediately, so for the subsequent tasks you need also to update the current fact value:

```
- set_fact:
    mgmt_ip: xx.xx.xx.xx
```